# subset a fixed number of values for each group in another column

Tags: r, loops, substring, subset

I have a data frame consisting of a number of species in one column and the name of the assembly in another column. For each species there are a variable number of assemblies;

```
especies1 --- assembly1
especies1 --- assembly2
especies1 --- assembly3
especies1 --- assemblyN

especies2 --- assembly1
especies2 --- assembly2
especies2 --- assemblyN
```

The problem is each species have a different large amount of assemblies (1000-100000 assemblies) so I want to generate a df with randomly selected 150 assemblies per species.

In that way a have exactly the same number of assemblies for each species.

I got really block on this,

I'll appreciate any suggestion!
Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `by` to split data frame by *species* and then within each subset draw the random 150 *assemblies*:

```
# BUILD LIST OF SAMPLED DATA FRAMES BY SPECIES
samples_list <- by(mydata, mydata$species, function(sub) sub[sample(nrow(sub), 150),])

# COMBINE LIST TO A SINGLE DATA FRAME
sample_df <- do.call(rbind, samples_list)
```

To explain above:

- `by` is the object-oriented function of `tapply` (so is part of the *apply* family) and essentially slices the input data frame, *mydata*, by the specified grouping column(s), *mydata$species*, and then passes each subset data frame into the `function` call given the name, *sub*:
- Inside the `function`, `sample` of all rows of subset data frame is run, picking 150 without replacement. This sample returns a vector of 150 row numbers and with extract `[` function further subsets the data frame using row indexing in format: `dataframe[row_index,]`;
- `do.call` + `rbind` is shorthand to `rbind` each data frame together with longer form: `rbind(samples_list[[1]], samples_list[[2]], samples_list[[3]], ...)`

Comment: Thank you! It works nicely XD I will try to understand each step of your code.

Comment: Thank you Parfait, it helps a lot! Regards and take care during this crazy and sad time...